# TChannel state change events?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, channelfactory

hopefully a simple WCF beginners question..

I have a WCF channel factory, returning a service proxy `TChannel`:

```
// setup connection to server
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(GetAppSetting("Endpoint"));
var tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IExcelServer>(this, tcpBinding, endpointAddress);
server = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

I would like to know when this service proxy changes state (Faulted, Closed etc). I can see events on the `ChannelFactory` itself, however I'm not sure this is the same as the channel itself, and even here stopping the server process doesn't cause a state transition.

This is a CallbackContract service, and in almost all interactions the server is sending data to the client. Therefore I can't simply rely on catching the failure when I make a server call from the client.

Should I send a heartbeat from client to server to trigger the state change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance you get back from `CreateChannel` implements `TChannel` but also [`IClientChannel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has state changed events like `Closed`, `Closing`, `Opened`, etc.:

```
server = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)server).Faulted += FaultedHandler;
```

P.S: As you pointed out, the states of the channel and channel factory are related but not the same. If a `Channel` is faulted it doesn't necessarily mean that the `ChannelFactory` is.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for that. I am still getting a suspicious cast warning from VS - adding IClientChannel to the class declaration isn't practical I guess.. is there an abstract class that I should be extending perhaps?

Comment: @MarkNuttall-Smith In this case you know more than VS. The instance will ALWAYS be IClientChannel but you can calm VS down by checking: `var clientChannel = server as IClientChannel; if (clientChannel != null) { clientChannel.Faulted += FaultedHandler; }`