# WCF ChannelFactory casting interface to IClientChannel suspisious cast

Tags: c#, wcf, dispose, channel, channelfactory

Using WCF ChannelFactory CreateChannel method of my custom interface -

```
ChannelFactory<MyServiceInterface> myFactory= 
new ChannelFactory<MyServiceInterface>(binding,endpoint);

MyServiceInterface clientInterface = myFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Reading a lot around the web, looks like I want to close my channel properly like -

```
private void ProperlyDisposeChannel(ICommunicationObject comObj)
        {
            bool success = false;

            if (comObj == null || comObj.State == CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                if (comObj.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    comObj.Close();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //optionally log exception
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        comObj.Abort();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //do not retry to abort, optionally log
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I am trying to cast my channel to IClientChannel (or maybe IChannel), but VS is warning me - 
Suspicious cast - there is no type in the solution that inherits both MyServiceInterface and System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel

I was under the impression that the proxy returned by the factory automatically implements IClientChannel. Am I wrong? What is this warning about? And what should I cast my channel to? And maybe my ProperlyDisposeChannel method should accept IClientChannel instead of ICommunicationObject (I prefer ICOmmuminationObject bec it will work for other objects too)

So I'm trying the following line which gives me the warning -

```
ProperlyDisposeChannel((IChannel)clientInterface);
```

or `ProperlyDisposeChannel((IClientChannel)clientInterface);`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250(v=vs.110).aspx - says returns The TChannel of type IChannel created by the factory.So not sure what's suspicious...

Comment: Where are you casting to IClientChannel?

Comment: In order to close - calling PropertyDisposeChannel((IChannel/IClientChannel)clientInterface). ill make the post clearer too

Comment: `there is no type in the solution that inherits both MyServiceInterface and System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel` so is this not true? Is there such a type or not in your solution? The C# compiler does not know anything about WCF. WCF is just a library like any other.

Comment: @MikeTurner did you see my comment? You interacted with other people on this page so you might have missed my question.

Comment: @usr - well - the proxy returned from the factory should be implementing TChannel and IChannel according to Microsoft docs. No?

Comment: How is the C# compiler supposed to know that? It does not know anything about WCF. I need you to answer my question before I can answer. Is there such a type or not in your solution?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear on the following: The C# compiler does not know what interfaces your runtime objects implement. How could it know? It warns you based on the static types that it sees in your source code.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082494/why-an-object-of-wcf-service-contract-interface-can-be-casted-to-iclientchannel) may give you your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the suspicious warning you got, you can do an explicit cast. Indeed the CreateChannel() signature returns the interface Type of your service but is also inheriting the IChannel interface under the wood.

This makes sense as the method cannot obviously return 2 types, allowing to use directly your service.

This is an implementation choice, it could have been returning, let's say, `public interface IChannel<T> : IChannel { T Instance {get;} }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ICommunicationObject` to do the close or abort - I do that all the time.

Simply change your call to:

```
ProperlyDisposeChannel((ICommunicationObject)clientInterface);
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the same suspicious cast warning as using IChannel

Comment: @MikeTurner - That is just bizzare.  We have an n-tier application that uses WCF between the layers and we use the exact same pattern and I've never seen this warning.  What is the type of `clientInterface`?  Is it `MyServiceInterace`?  Can you post the code for `MyServiceInterface`?

Comment: MyServiceInterface-
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface MyServiceInterface 
    {
        [OperationContract
        methods...
     }

Comment: Just a plain interface not specifically implement ICommunicationObject or IChannel... do I need to? Looking at the link in SOS's comment - looks like the object returned implements IChannel automatically

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement the interfaces in your contract - the WCF framework will do that for you when it creates the channel.  `IChannel` implements `ICommunicationObject`, so the cast should be legal.  Maybe there's something else going on in your code that isn't readily apparent?

Comment: when you try the same thing and cast as either IChannel or ICommunicationObject - does resharper or VS give you any warning?

Comment: We don't use ReSharper and I've never seen that warning when casting from `ICommunicationObject`.

Comment: Do you think it's safe to proceed and ignore the warning? Code is running just fine for me... Also - any diff then if I cast to ICommunicationObject or IChannel?

Comment: I see here another user has a similar experience - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249404/tchannel-state-change-events

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer suggest using `as` to make the cast to calm VS down.  You might try `ProperlyDisposeChannel(clientInterface as IClientChannel);` - just make sure you check in the method that the parameter isn't null (the result of a failed cast via `as`).

Comment: THanks. I tried the safe cast with as and IT STILL GIVES THE WARNING! about the null check - thx for the tip, already checking that...

Comment: Beyond bizzare....this one has me stumped (not that that is an unusual state for me, but still :) ).